# How to set a dynamic class in react js and retrieve it in Jquery

Tags: reactjs

I want to set dynamic classname in reactjs so that I can retrieve the classname for different div. Actually, I have 4 collapsible for that I have different div with the same content but functionality different. There I need to specify the different classname there so that I can retrieve the classname when I click on the particular div. And I want to retrieve that classname also inside the jquery. Please help me out in react js code.

nothing

Answer (score 0):

I created 3 dynamic divs using an array containing names and I give them a class with the respective name, to access the class you can use `el.target.className`, then you can use JQuery the way you want with the class (divClass), in this case I'm selecting the element.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import $ from "jquery";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const names = ['Lukas', 'Jhon', 'Ana']
    return (
      <div>
        {names.map(name => (
          <div
            className={name}
            onClick={(el) => {
              const divClass = el.target.className
              console.log($(`.${divClass}`))
            }}
          >
            {name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is a live example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qcheyr?file=index.js